# I do not understand the option -t in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not understand this option, I do understand the wording, but I do not understand when this situation occurs.

> **-t** -  Issue a warning when a source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab
>   expressed in spaces.

So if it is possible someone to explain me when it depends on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces.
If I make a tab it is counted as 4 spaces. One time `\t =  4 * \s` Right ?

If I have `\t\s\s` or `\s\t\s` isn' that the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not within one line, but between different lines. For example, in code like this:

```
if a:
····if b:
········print("X")
⇥print("Y")
```

If tab is 4 spaces, `Y` prints if `a`. If tab is 8 spaces, `Y` prints if `a` and `b`. If tab is any other setting, it is invalid code.

Less importantly, it is confusing that these two commands should be at the same indent level (as long as tab > 2 spaces):

```
··⇥print("X")
⇥print("Y")
```

because tabs don't blindly convert to spaces, but jump forward to specific columns. So,

> If I have `\t\s\s` or `\s\t\s` isn' that the same?

That is correct. Given tab = 4 spaces setting, the former will end at column 6 (go to column 4, advance 1, advance 1), while the latter ends on column 5 (advance 1, go to column 4, advance 1).